# Vuex function execute before the other

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, vuex

I am using **Vue + Vuex** to delete the user token from **localStorage** to make the user logout and redirect them to login page.

> Component logout method Code:

```
methods: {
      logout () {
        this.$store.dispatch('logout')
          .then(response => {
            this.$router.push({ name: 'login'});
          }).catch((e) => {
            console.log(e);
          });
      }
    }
```

> Store action code:

```
logout({commit}) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        commit('logout');
        resolve("done");
      } catch (e) {
        reject(e);
      }
    });
  }
```

> Store Mutation function:

```
logout (state) {
    localStorage.removeItem('user');
    state.is_logged_in = false;
    state.user = null;
  }
```

> Problem is:

What happen is:

1. User redirect to Login page.
2. User redirect back to dashboard.
3. User access token is removed.

So the user stay in the same page.

> This means:

The action method is dispatched then it returns back to the component logout method then it commit the mutation.

Comment: I cannot see any way in the code above that anything could happen before the `commit('logout')` is executed. I suspect there's an async call in there somewhere that OP is a) not showing, and b) not waiting to complete

Comment: @Phil is that the right way to redirect after logging the user out and deleting his localStorage?

Comment: Is _"what"_ the right way?

Answer (score 0):

I will just show you my logout function, perhpas it will help you:

```
  logout() {
      this.$store.dispatch("setToken", null);
      this.$store.dispatch("setAdmin", null);
      this.$router.push({
        name: "root"
      });
    }
```

and in the store:

```
mutations: {
    setToken (state, token) {
      state.token = token
      if (token) {
        state.isAdminLoggedIn = true
      } else {
        state.isAdminLoggedIn = false
      }
    },
    setAdmin (state, admin) {
      state.admin = admin
    }
  },
  actions: {
    setToken ({ commit }, token) {
      commit('setToken', token)
    },
    setAdmin ({ commit }, admin) {
      commit('setAdmin', admin)
    }
```